# MySQL Table structure not updated in Doctrine ORM Entity

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Its symfony 2 - doctrine issue.

I was trying to add some more fields to one of my tables in MySQL. After modification, i had run the command doctrine mapping import and doctrine generate entities commands, but the Entity_name.php file under Bundle/Entity/ folder not getting updated. Can anyone help me ?

Thanks and regards,
Tismon Varghese

Comment: Hi, is it only entity file not getting updated? How about the imported ORM file? Is it getting updated with newly inserted fields? If only Entity file is not getting updated, perhaps you are not seeing the generated fields. It'll amend to the end of the file not recreate the whole file. Try running a search for that new field / see bottom of the page. If the field is still not there, recreate the entity by deleting the entity file manually. Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your message is brief, but my interpretation is that you are trying to ADD more fields to an existing table, by creating a NEW entity. This doesn't sound like the correct workflow. The entity ought to already exist, and to add fields to the table, will require adding new properties, correctly annotated, to the existing Entity.

What commands are you running, and what command line output are you seeing? The doctrine based SF2 commands offer reasonable information upon failure.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).